# Specifying multiple types for a parameter - error with parameter passing

Tags: typescript, types, parameters

Why does this piece of code fail?

```
/**
 * Write the provided contents to a file in the specified directory.
 */
public writeFile(subPath: string, contents: string | Object) {
  // stringify the contents if they are not already
  if (contents && typeof contents === 'object') contents = JSON.stringify(contents);

  this.file.writeFile(this.path, subPath, contents);
}
```

With the following error:

```
Argument of type 'string | Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | ArrayBuffer | Blob'. Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'string | ArrayBuffer | Blob'. The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead? Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Blob'. The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead? Property 'size' is missing in type 'Object'.
```

I understand `writeFile(...);` does not accept an `Object` for its third property, `text`. But, I have stringified it in the if statement...

The signature to `writeFile(...);` looks like this:

```
/** Write a new file to the desired location.
 *
 * @param {string} path Base FileSystem. Please refer to the iOS and Android filesystems above
 * @param {string} fileName path relative to base path
 * @param {string | Blob} text content or blob to write
 * @param {IWriteOptions} options replace file if set to true. See WriteOptions for more information.
 * @returns {Promise<any>} Returns a Promise that resolves to updated file entry or rejects with an error.
 */
writeFile(path: string, fileName: string, text: string | Blob | ArrayBuffer, options?: IWriteOptions): Promise<any>;
```

The error asks if I meant to use `any` - I did not, since I want stricter control as I'd like to control what can and cannot be passed to this function.

How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

Use another variable for the stringified `contents`.

Typescript can't know in **compile time** will your contents be parsed into the string or will stay as `object`.

Compiler don't see what are you doing in the `if` statement. It sees only that the type of `contents` is `string | object`, so there may be an `object` and when you pass it to the `writeFile` function parameter, which is only `string`, it complains you about it.

Look that I have called `toString()` on the `contents` to assure compiler that 2 sides of my ternary operator returns `string`.

```
public writeFile(subPath: string, contents: string | Object) {

      if(!contents) {
         contents = '';
      }

      const contentsAsString: string = typeof contents === 'object' ? 
                               JSON.stringify(contents) : contents.toString();      

      this.file.writeFile(this.path, subPath, contentsAsString);
}
```

Comment: The type guard works on the ternary operator so long as you can remove the null check: `const contentsAsString: string = typeof contents === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(contents) : contents; `

Comment: The `toString()' won't be called in that case as `null` is an `Object`, instead you would get 'null' in the file. Best would be to compile with strict null checks and then you never get a null, otherwise a simple `if (!contents) contents = '';` at the top of the function would make it safe.